# Possible reason for error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

I am doing a sample application where I have declared a struct:

```
 // common.h
 typedef struct MyStruct
 {
   int a;
 }

  //sample.h
  #include "common.h"
  int main()
  {
     MyStruct st;// getting error here
  }
```

> C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier

What are the possible reasons for this?

Comment: Is `MyStruct` defined before creating an object of that type?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two things:

First, you're missing a semi-colon after the struct definition:

```
 // common.h
 typedef struct MyStruct
 {
     int a;
 };
  ^
```

Not that this is still wrong. You will need to fix the other error.

Second, you should define the struct like this:

```
 // common.h
 typedef struct
 {
     int a;
 } MyStruct;
```

Alternatively, you can define it like this:

```
 // common.h
 struct MyStruct
 {
     int a;
 };
```

Comment: That first and second example are wrong-ish by the way. Not in the sense it will stop your code from compiling, just that the `typedef` is superfluous without an actual aliasing type. And your second contention is wrong (that you _need_ to do it that way), you can create a `struct xyzzy` and then creates variables with it in C++ with just `xyzzy varname`, as you show in your third example.

Comment: I know, it was just to point out the missing semi-colon. I will edit to make that clear.

Answer (score 1):

It's almost *always* because the type `MyStruct` isn't defined at that point, either because you're including the wrong header or the type specification fails for some reason.

If that typedef is *exactly* what you have in your `common.h`, it won't work. It should be followed by the aliasing type and a semicolon. Or perhaps you didn't *want* a typedef since C++ allows you to refer to `MyStruct` as a "proper" type in the source code.

Something like this works fine:

```
struct MyStruct { int a; };
int main() {
    MyStruct st;
    return 0;
}
```

Or even this, showing the three possibilities:

```
struct MyStruct { int a; };
typedef struct MyStruct2 { int a; } xyzzy;
int main() {
    MyStruct st;
    MyStruct2 st2;
    xyzzy st3;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `"common.h"` header does not define `MyStruct` properly; it needs a semi-colon on the end.

Then the `typedef` is vacuous; in C++, you don't need the `typedef` to get type `MyStruct` defined.  (In C, you'd need to write:

```
typedef struct MyStruct { int a; } MyStruct;
```

But C++ does not require that - though it does not object to it, either.)

So, it would be sufficient to write:

```
struct MyStruct { int a; };
```